# Magento Get Products By Manufacturer

Tags: php, magento

I have the following code which gets me a list of manufacturers:

```
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
                    ->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');

    $valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getData('attribute_id'))
                ->setStoreFilter(0, false);

    $preparedManufacturers = array();            
    foreach($valuesCollection as $value) {
        $preparedManufacturers[$value->getOptionId()] = $value->getValue();
    }   


    if (count($preparedManufacturers)) {
        echo "<h2>Manufacturers</h2><ul>";
        foreach($preparedManufacturers as $optionId => $value) {
            echo "<li>" . $value . " - (ID:" . $optionId . ")</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

How do I get the first product of each manufacturer?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have just tried it and it is working :-).

Comment: Do you know by any chance how I could paginate this? eg. get 10 records per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     if (count($preparedManufacturers)) {
    echo "<h2>Manufacturers</h2><ul>";
    foreach($preparedManufacturers as $optionId => $value) {
  <!-- add the this code for get first item id -->
    $firstProductId=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(0)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$optionId)->getFirstItem()->getId();
        echo "<li>" . $value . " - (ID:" . $optionId . ")</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```